# insertion on BIT column in mysql from Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, zend-framework2

I need to update two columns in a table in mysql. I have written following code in ZF2 model

```
$sql = new Sql($dbAdapter);
$update = $sql->update();
$update->table($table_name)
       ->set(array('checksum' => '', 'mailed_status' => 0))
       ->where('id = ' . $record_id);

$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($update);
$statement->execute();
```

Here in the above code, checksum is varchar column and mailed_status is bit column. The above query only updates checksum field but the mailed_status remains same (previously 1)
When I was updating mailed_status as 1, it works. I mean it updates 0 to 1 but the vice versa is not working.

I have printed the query and found that it makes quote around digit like this: '0' and '1'.

But I am wondering here. '1' is working but '0' is not, why?
What is the proper solution for this? Temporarily I changed the bit data type to varchar(1) in mysql database's table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thats because 0 is treated like a Null value when updating your database. Changing column type to varchar(1) it's simpler than override sql update method!